# Funciones y casting en clojure

Tags: clojure

Estoy iniciando con Clojure y tengo este problema: 
Necesito ingresar por teclado dos números y comparar cuál es el mayor o si son iguales. Me da un error de casting y tampoco me lee la función con lo valores que ingreso por teclado. LLevar esto de Python a Clojure:

Python

```
def max (n1, n2):
    if n1 < n2:
       print n2
    elif n2 < n1:
       print n1
    else:
       print "They are equals."
```

Clojure

```
(import '(java.util Scanner))
(def scan (Scanner. *in*))
(println "Numero 1: ")
(def num1 (.nextLine scan))
(println "Numero 2: ")
(def num2 (.nextLine scan))
(Integer/parseInt num1)
(Integer/parseInt num2)
(print "Tu numero1 = " num1  "y tu numero2 = " num2)



(defn max [num1 num2]
(if (< num1 num2)
(println "Mayor:" num2)  
(println "Mayor:" num1)
 ))
```

Necesito que en Clojure funcione igual que en Python.

Answer (score 3):

`(Integer/parseInt num1)` no altera `num1`. Debido a que los números son inmutables, deberá vincular el número pasado a una nueva variable. Así es como escribiría lo que estás tratando de hacer:

```
(import '(java.util Scanner))

(defn max [num1 num2]
  (if (< num1 num2)
    (println "Mayor:" num2)
    (println "Mayor:" num1)))

(let [scanner (Scanner. *in*)
      _ (println "Numero 1: ")
      num1 (.nextLine scanner)

      _ (println "Numero 2: ")
      num2 (.nextLine scanner)

      parsed-num1 (Integer/parseInt num1) ; aquí
      parsed-num2 (Integer/parseInt num2)] ; y aquí

  (println "Tu numero1 =" parsed-num1  "y tu numero2 = " parsed-num2)
  (max parsed-num1 parsed-num2))
```

Hice algunos otros cambios:

- Cambié de usar `def` a`let`. `let` siempre debe ser preferido.
- `max` es una función incorporada. Evite crear sus propias funciones con nombres incorporados.

(Nota, no sé español. Perdón si Google Translate escupe algo raro.)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó muy bien.